# How to "conan install" libudev package for arm arch?

Tags: cross-platform, conan, udev, libudev

The "libudev/system" available on conancenter for x86 arch:

https://conan.io/center/libudev?os=Linux&tab=configuration

When installing to x86 it is working:

```
sudo conan install libudev/system@ -pr ./conan/profiles/x86_64 --build=missing -r conancenter -c tools.system.package_manager:mode=install
```

When installing to arm it is failing:

```
sudo conan install libudev/system@ -pr ./conan/profiles/arm --build=missing -r conancenter -c tools.system.package_manager:mode=install -c tools.system.package_manager:sudo=True
```

Resulting:

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libudev-dev:armhf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libudev-dev:armhf
libudev/system: ERROR: while executing system_requirements(): Error 100 while executing sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libudev-dev:armhf
ERROR: Error in system requirements
```

Notes:

- Running in docker container
- Conan version 1.53.0

Also tried:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ apt search libudev-dev
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libudev-dev/oldoldstable 232-25+deb9u14 amd64
  libudev development files
```

Expecting "libudev-dev:armhf" to be found

Comment: Quick hint: it shouldn't be necessary to run Conan with sudo ``sudo conan ...``. Conan can run (and should run) without it. It is likely that the recipe in ConanCenter might not be prepared to install in Linux-ARM, it might be worth reporting it there: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues

Comment: @Frant have you configured you system to add armhf packages? `dpkg --add-architecture armhf`, then you need to run `apt update`. Otherwise, arm packages will not be available in your cache